# three.js script not working in node.js server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, three.js, backend

I'm new to web dev and im trying to run a threejs app on a nodejs server and the script main.js in the html won't execute:

```
<body>
    <script src="../project/node_modules/three/build/three.js"></script>
    <script src="../project/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is my node code, the server itself works:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require("fs");
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/html"});

    fs.readFile("index.html", function(error, data){
        if(error){
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.write("Error: file not found");
        }else{
            res.write(data);
        }
        res.end();
    });
    
});

server.listen(port, function (error) {
    if (error){ 
        console.log("Something went wrong", error);
    }else{
        console.log("Server listening on port: "+port);
    }
});
```

I checked the Network in DevTools and the server response is the html file.
I've been looking everywhere for a few hours and I can't find a solution, I'd be happy if you can help me out, thanks.

Comment: You have to expose a folder as a static files container with `app.use(express.static('public'))` where public is the folder name: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html. Then move the index.html and all the JS files inside this folder instead of writing a HTTP request handler for this

Comment: I don't think I got you right but I'm not using express :) @Guerric P

Comment: Oh yes I read too fast sorry. Is there a particular reason why you're not using express? `http` is very low level. If you keep using `http` then you have to create an URL which serves the JS file to the web page, just like you did for the `index.html`. Express.js helps map URLs to handlers while `http` doesn't so you have to write your own logic based on the `req` object

Comment: Oh I understand. I will try to do it with express. Looks easier, thanks @Guerric P